# Drupal 7 - Placing Content Body in a Lightbox

Tags: drupal-7, lightbox

I am working on a drupal 7 site that utilizes the calendar module. I've created a content type "event" which includes an event title, description, and time.

I'd like to display this information into a lightbox of some sort. I've researched the lightbox2 and colorbox modules but it seems that those are mainly used for media.

Has anyone done this and/or are there any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar module has a popup option built in.  If you'd like another alternative you can look at the [Fullcalendar module](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) which has color box integration and is a better calendar in my opinion anyway.

Comment: oh my gosh, I feel so silly... do you know where the popup option is located? It doesn't appear to be a content-type option

Comment: It should be in the Calendar view settings.